# Resource not found by Assets controller

Tags: playframework, routes, yeoman

I have developed a play-java application which uses yeoman routing. After migrating play from ***2.4*** to ***2.5***, the application works fine and the GUI is loaded in the browser when it runs from the IDE(intellij idea) on my local machine, when a dist file is created(an activator clean followed by an activator dist) and I try to deploy and run it from the server, back-end is working fine, but no UI components are loaded (with a 404 Not Found error) and I only get the following message in the browser.

> "Resource not found by Assets controller"

The routes file has the following commands

```
GET    /                com.tuplejump.playYeoman.Yeoman.redirectRoot(base="/ui/")
GET    /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET    /ui              com.tuplejump.playYeoman.Yeoman.index
->     /ui/             yeoman.Routes
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to the build.sbt file solved the problem

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, Yeoman, PlayEbean).settings(
  com.tuplejump.sbt.yeoman.Yeoman.projectSettings: _*    //this line
)
```